# csv file not creating in a directory

Tags: python-2.7, csv, module, directory, operating-system

The directory is correctly located but csv file is not created in that folder.

Code used to create a folder:

```
 self.directory = os.path.join('Admins/'+name+'/')
 os.makedirs(self.directory)
```

Code:

```
 wfile = open(str(self.directory) + '/' + 'SALES.CSV', 'a+')
```

error:

```
 no 'SALES.CSV' found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to rely on `os.path.join()` you might want to use it the way it is intended :
`os.path.join(p1, p2, p3)`
Without any slashes. You might also want to use

```
with open(os.path.join(self.directory, "SALES.CSV"), 'a+') as wfile:
    # Process the file as you like, it will close itself afterwards
```

Mind trying this and letting us know the results?

Edit : just realised something.

You are using 'a+' which means you open the file in 'append' mode. But since you just created the directory, I suspect the file doesn't exist in the first place. If you want to open one anyway, just replace 'a+' with 'w'.

Comment: I have made changes according to the above answer. but this result is partly working. csv file is created where the py file is present and not in the directory. can anyone help me on that.